# Using apply on a pandas DataFrame with a function that returns another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a function that takes a Series as input and returns a DataFrame. I want to run this function on every row in a DataFrame and collect all the rows from all the returned DataFrames into a single DataFrame. I know that whenever you want to do something over all rows, apply is the go-to function, but because the function returns a DataFrame, I'm not sure how to use apply to produce the result I need. What is the best way to do this? Is this where the itertuples function that I always see "don't use this, use apply instead" should actually be used?

Comment: What are the returned DataFrames like? Are they just a single column or something?

Comment: No, they have 4 columns

Comment: Why wouldn't you rewrite your function to take the whole dataframe as an argument, and process it line by line creating another dataframe, incrementally concatenating to itself in each row. I don't think ```.apply``` is an option here, cause it cannot really return more than it took, vertically at least (in general). Otherwise- you would need to share more details, you can only theorize as your question stands now...

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski Well that's basically what I'm asking. It seems like generally writing code that takes a dataframe and explicitly processes it line by line is a red flag, so I'm just making sure it's a reasonable thing to do here.

Comment: `pd.concat(df_function(df.iloc[i]) for i in range(len(df)))`?

Comment: @QuangHoang If you're going to do what why not just use `itertuples()`?

Comment: @AMC if I'm not mistaken, they basically are the same thing, and also `apply`. List comprehension is just sort of a more vanilla way than `apply`, which might save some overhead.

Comment: Thanks @QuangHoang I'm using your solution